# Flutter firebase analytics multiple projects

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

Is there a way to switch firebase analytics project on running flutter app?

Scenario: We have e-commerce web portals in few countries (each on subdomain). For each we have separate web firebase analytics projects.

Now we develop mobile app (one common for all countries). Inside app user can select particular shop. We want target events to proper analytics mobile project.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: On top of my head solution could be to use events with extra fields to decide the country by which you can filter out!

Comment: My goal is to send to different analytics project - not to one with filtering

Comment: You can only link one Google Analytics property per Firebase project

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way to use multiple Firebase apps with Firebase Analytics. This is a long-standing feature request - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/230.